# How to change the key repeat interval?

Tags: terminal, freebsd

How can I change the key repeat interval in FreeBSD?  I'm talking about when you hold down a key, and the terminal repeatedly registers key presses for that key.

I'm having a problem where if I type a long line of text at the prompt and then hold down the backspace key, it deletes, but very slowly. I estimate that it's deleting about 5 characters per second, which sounds fast, but it's not. For comparison, try the same thing in Notepad or your browser.

Comment: Under X or on the console?

Answer (score 2):

You may try some values with `xset r rate`. This command will enable auto-repeat, but you can follow it by 2 numbers. The first one is the number of ms before auto-repeat starts, the second is the number of repeats by seconds. For example:

```
xset r rate 300 20
```

The auto-repeat will start after 300 ms, then will repeat 20 times/second.